# dataTables with dynamic id's

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using Data-table plugin for `jQuery` with HTML, php and `MySQL`. Everything is ok when I explicitly set the id of the table but if I loop over a `MySQL` result jquery doesn't "understand" the table id. Maybe with the code it's more clear.

DataTable working fine:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-tabletools">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 60px; text-align: center;">Id</th>
      <th style="width: 400px; text-align: center;">Info A</th>
      <th style="width: 390px; text-align: center;">Info B</th>
      <th style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- tbody dynamically populated -->
  </tbody>
</table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatable-tabletools').DataTable({
     });
   });
 </script>
```

DataTable not working:

```
<?php
foreach ($sections as $section)
{
   $insc = Inscripciones::getAllInscriptionBySection($section -> getId());
   if (count($insc) > 0)
   {
     ?>
     <h2 style="margin-bottom: 50px;"><?php echo $section->getNombre(); ?></h2>
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-tabletools-<?php echo $section -> getId(); ?>">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th style="width: 60px; text-align: center;">Id</th>
           <th style="width: 450px; text-align: center;">Category</th>
           <th style="width: 390px; text-align: center;">Title</th>
           <th style="width: 140; text-align: center;">Usuario</th>
           <th style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">Acciones</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <!-- tbody also dynamically populated -->
       </tbody>
     </table>
  <?php
  }
}
  ?>



    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#datatable-tabletools-1').DataTable({
           });
           $('#datatable-tabletools-2').DataTable({
           })
           $('#datatable-tabletools-3').DataTable({
           })
          });
   </script>
```

The curious thing is that in the rendered source code the table id is shown as "datatable-tabletools-1", "datatable-tabletools-2", and so on...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your current code. 
You can try applying datatable using a class selector. 
$('.table').DataTable({ });

Comment: Hi @Pramod , I tried with classes in a new and clean script and works like a charm so I suppose that I'm missing something else...

Comment: Great!. Classes should be fine  as long as you have common datatable initializing code.